# Data comes into console but does not show in application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

- All data comes into console but does not show into app

```
import React from 'react'
const Question_Answer_model = (props) => {
  console.log(props.data)
  const newvar = props.data.map((item) => {
    return (
      <li>{item.question_text}</li>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Question And Answers...</h2>
        {newvar}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Question_Answer_model
```

> this is my console[data which shows in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhUvZ.png)
> [here all comes into array in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhUvZ.png)

Comment: did you add Question_Answer_model  component into your app?

Comment: can you try `item.data.question_text` ?

Comment: yes its works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think this will help you

```
import React from 'react'
const Question_Answer_model = (props) => {
  //console.log(props)
  const newvar = props.data.map((item) => {
    return (
        <li>{item.data.question_text}</li>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2></h2>
        {newvar}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Question_Answer_model
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newvar = props.data.map((item) => {
return (
  <li>{item.question_text}</li>
)
```

})

This should be wrapped inside useCallback/useMemo/memberFunction.

It is not displaying because it is rendering for the first time and rendering when you get data.

Solved E.g

```
const { data } = props;
const newvar = useCallback(() => {
data.map((item) => {
    return (
      <li>{item.question_text}</li>
    )
  })
}, [data ])
```

use newvar inside return